# Cordova FCM Plugin - Google Services Plugin Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, cordova-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm following instructions from *https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm* to use FCM plugin in my ionic 1 project, but I'm get in trouble.

When I run "ionic run android" I get:

```
> Could not open dsl remapped class cache for 90dph5obcol5uraf1d1h262ym (C:\Users\arivan\.gradle\caches\2.13\scripts-remapped\condoclass_FCMPlugin_auvalosjdpfzmwa03yh9kenur\90dph5obcol5uraf1d1h262ym\dsl-1812427186).
   > Could not open dsl generic class cache for script 'C:\Projetos\condo-class\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-fcm\condoclass-FCMPlugin.gradle' (C:\Users\arivan\.gradle\caches\2.13\scripts\90dph5obcol5uraf1d1h262ym\dsl\dsl-1812427186).
      > com/google/gms/googleservices/GoogleServicesPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

If I comment line

```
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

in *platforms\android\cordova-plugin-fcm\MyProject-FCMPlugin.gradle* file, the build process runs succesfully, but my app crashs on startup.

Following is my project plugin list:

```
com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions 0.6.5 "Native Page Transitions"
com.telerik.plugins.wkwebview 0.6.9 "WKWebView Polyfill"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-fcm 1.1.4 "FCMPlugin"
cordova-plugin-file 4.2.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.4.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Following is my Android SDK Manager "Extras" section:

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [issue link](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/7).

You may have to tweak in project.properties and FCMPlugin.gradle as mentioned in the link.

In project.properties add,

> cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2
>   cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2
>   cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2

In FCMPlugin.gradle,

> dependencies { compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
>   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2' }

`project.properties` file is under `platforms/android/` directory.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

You may update Google Play Services and Google Repository via SDK manager as described in the plugin page.

- Android Support Library version 23 or greater
- Android Support Repository version 20 or greater
- Google Play Services version 27 or greater
- Google Repository version 22 or greater

Comment: I already have installed the mentioned libraries: Android Support Repository 38, Android Support Library 23.2.1, Google Play Services 32 and Google Repository 32.